# Accessing the image in HTTP server from a seperate image DB server

Tags: postgresql, backup

I have a PostgreSql db that has several OID fields. The data to these fields has been inserted using the **lo_import** command.

But I am not able to backup the database and restore it in another server. If I try to do so, all the text entries get restored and the OID fields have a OID value, but doing an **lo_export** gives me an error like the File does not exist.

What is it that I am doing wrong here?

---

**[Edit:]** Ok, I have found that the DB backup actually works but I have another unique problem. My DB server and my HTTP server are on different machines. So now my question is how do I retrieve the image in the HTTP server from the image server?

Comment: Different languages/drivers provide different methods for retrieving large object contents on a database connection through a network. libpq (the basic C postgresql client library) has functions named lo_open, lo_read, lo_close... Other languages expose similar functions built on top of these. The exact answer for your application depends on which language/PG driver it uses.

Comment: I am using PHP as the server side scripting language. For now I was able to come up with a solution considering both as separate servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a PHP code snippet demonstrating how to serve an image from a PostgreSQL large object to an HTTP connection:

```
  $db=pg_connect("dbname=mydb host=dbserver");
  pg_query("BEGIN");
  $p = pg_query("SELECT object_id, image_type FROM contents WHERE id=$some_id");
  list($oid,$type) = pg_fetch_row($p);
  $h=pg_lo_open($db, $oid, "r");
  if ($h) {
    header("Content-Type: $type");
    pg_lo_read_all($h);
    pg_lo_close($h);
  }
  pg_query("END");
```

Comment: Wow, this looks good. I will try this out and come back. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry what is Io_import? dumping Postgresql databases is done with pg_dump, restoring with pg_restore or the psql command.

Comment: I have a column called image that is of the type OID. To insert an image to this column, I use lo_import() function.